# Touch manipulation move on initial offset issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a `ManipulationDelta` event to drag a `Canvas` as follows:

```
private Point lastMovePosition;

private void MoveCanvas(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.ManipulationOrigin;

    if (CanvasShareSwarm.Scale > 1) //Force zoom out limit to view all
    {
        CanvasShareSwarm.Offset -= position - lastMovePosition;
        lastMovePosition = position;
    }
}
```

This works but when the drag starts the `Canvas` always jumps back to what seems to be a previous position before moving. I suspect it has to do with my `lastMovePosition` point.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you would have to initialize the `lastMovePosition` field in a [ManipulationStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationstarted.aspx) event handler:

```
private void OnManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    lastMovePosition = e.ManipulationOrigin;
}
```

Comment: On bended knee before your great knowledge.